# match if directory exists and string has "\" in while loop using "&&" and "||" in bash

Tags: bash, while-loop

I am trying to take an input from user and check if that directory exists AND has `"/"` in it, inside a while statement but I am not sure what the correct syntax is :

```
while [[ ! -d ${GATHER_DIRPATH}/${STREAM_NAME} && "$STREAM_NAME" !=
 *\/* ]] || [ -z ${STREAM_NAME} ];
```

when i give input as `"Folder1/Folder2"`, it should check if this directory exists and also check if the string has `"/"` in it or not.

I need to negate the condition but with && condition
This is Working :
[[ ! -d ${GATHER_DIRPATH}/${STREAM_NAME} || "$STREAM_NAME" != */* ]]

This is not working (I NEED THIS ONE TO WORK):
[[ ! -d ${GATHER_DIRPATH}/${STREAM_NAME} && "$STREAM_NAME" != */* ]]
First example is working fine but when I use && instead of ||, Condition is not evaluated correctly.
My condition should only enter WHILE loop when(both these conditions meet):
Condition A) Directory does not exists
AND
Condition B) Stream name does not contains /(forward slash) operator. (I have to use this condition because STREAM_NAME passed will always contain 2 folders, eg: folderA/folderB .  That's why I have to check forward slash contains to make sure user have entered two folders to be precise)
(If you have better approach for condition B please let me know)

Comment: You should add the current output and the expected one.

Answer (score 1):

To test whether a variable contains a given substring, one common pattern is to test whether removing that substring changes the value.  If it's not found, the values will be the same:

```
test "$STREAM_NAME" = "${STREAM_NAME#*/}"
```

Here we remove everything up to and including the first `/` - if there is no `/`, the strings will compare equal.  We could have used the Bash-specific `"${STREAM_NAME/\/}"`, but why not write portable code when it's easy to do so?

We can combine this with the test for a directory existing (you might also want to test that it's writeable); we do the string test first to avoid waiting for disk I/O if we already fail:

```
while test "$STREAM_NAME" = "${STREAM_NAME#*/}" \
   || ! test -d "${GATHER_DIRPATH}/${STREAM_NAME}" \
   || ! test -w "${GATHER_DIRPATH}/${STREAM_NAME}"
do read -p "directory name: " STREAM_NAME
done
```

Answer (score 0):

to check if this directory exists and also check if the string has "/" in it or not.

```
[[ -d ${GATHER_DIRPATH}/${STREAM_NAME} && "$STREAM_NAME" = */* ]]
```

to negate the condition :

```
[[ ! -d ${GATHER_DIRPATH}/${STREAM_NAME} || "$STREAM_NAME" != */* ]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,Appreciate it.
However,I need to negate the condition but with && condition
Your example:
[[ ! -d ${GATHER_DIRPATH}/${STREAM_NAME} || "$STREAM_NAME" != */* ]]

What I need:
[[ ! -d ${GATHER_DIRPATH}/${STREAM_NAME} && "$STREAM_NAME" != */* ]]

Comment: Your example is working fine but when I use && instead of ||, Condition is not evaluated correctly.
My condition should only enter WHILE loop when(both these conditions meet):
Condition A) Directory exists
AND
Condition B) Stream name contains /(forward slash) operator. (I have to use this condition because STREAM_NAME passed will always contain 2 folders, eg: folderA/folderB .  That's why I have to check forward slash contains to make sure user have entered two folders to be precise)
(If you have better approach for condition B please let me know)